# Facebook Permissions - can I use one permisson for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I have similar iOS and Android apps, and both need publish permission from Facebook. Do I need to send both apps for review, or it will be enough to send just one app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to apply separately for every platform. For every platform, you have to provide a demo app, and for every platform, you will separately receive permissions.

Comment: Do you have any proof link or it from personal experience?

Comment: see the developer docs. I can't provide a link right now as the firewall doesn't let me access FB here; I'll try to provide a link later. And yes, I've done this before. I know the approval process inside out.

Comment: Thanks, please provide the link when you will have opportunity.

Comment: I'll do that today evening.

Comment: @anber: here it is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#adding

Answer (score 0):

While integrating facebook with your android app,you need to add your Android development key hash to your Facebook developer profile to generate a key hash.

However, If you already have a Facebook app with an App ID that represents the same app on another platform, you can use the same app ID for iOS.

Comment: Thanks, but question was about another problem.